# Sorting an ArrayList of top scores

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment5
{
    public static void initialize(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> scores)
    {
       // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

       // Ask the user for the names and scores for 5 people.
       System.out.println("Enter the name for score #1: ");
       names.add(keyboard.next());
       System.out.println("Enter the score for score #1: ");
       scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());
       System.out.println("Enter the name for score #2: ");
       names.add(keyboard.next());
       System.out.println("Enter the score for score #2: ");
       scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());
       System.out.println("Enter the name for score #3: ");
       names.add(keyboard.next());
       System.out.println("Enter the score for score #3: ");
       scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());
       System.out.println("Enter the name for score #4: ");
       names.add(keyboard.next());
       System.out.println("Enter the score for score #4: ");
       scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());
       System.out.println("Enter the name for score #5: ");
       names.add(keyboard.next());
       System.out.println("Enter the score for score #5: ");
       scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());
    } 

    public static void sort(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> scores)
    {
    }

    public static void display(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> scores)
    {
       for (int index = 0; index < names.size(); index++)
       {
          String userNames = names.get(index);
          System.out.println(names.get(index));
       }

       for (int index = 0; index < scores.size(); index++)
       {
          Integer userScores = scores.get(index);
          System.out.println(scores.get(index));
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       // Create an ArrayList for names and scores.
       ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       // Call the three methods.
       initialize(names, scores);
       sort(names, scores);
       display(names, scores);
    }
}
```

Write a program that records high-score data for a fictitious game. The program will ask the user to enter five names, and five scores. It will store the data in memory, and print it back out sorted by score.

The output from your program should look approximately like this:

Enter the name for score #1: Suzy

Enter the score for score #1: 600

Enter the name for score #2: Kim

Enter the score for score #2: 9900

Enter the name for score #3: Bob

Enter the score for score #3: 1012

Enter the name for score #4: Armando

Enter the score for score #4: 8000

Enter the name for score #5: Tim

Enter the score for score #5: 514

Top Scorers:

Kim: 9900

Armando: 8000

Bob: 1012

Suzy: 600

Tim: 514

Requirements

The data must be stored in two ArrayLists: one ArrayList of strings named names, and one ArrayList of Integers named scores.  These ArrayLists must be declared in the main method.

All of the user input should be done in a method named InitializeArrays. It should have the following signature:

public static void InitializeArrays(ArrayList names, ArrayList scores)

You should write a function that sorts both array lists, based on the values in the scores array list. This is one of the more conceptually challenging parts of the assignment. You want to sort the scores array list, and simultaneously alter the names array list so that the names continue to line up with their respective scores by index. In the example data above, when the score 9900 moves to the first element of the scores array list, the name “Kim” should also be moved to the top of the names array list. The function should have the following signature:

public static void sort(ArrayList names, ArrayList scores)

Finally you should write a method that displays the contents of the two array lists. It should have the following signature:

public static void display(ArrayList names, ArrayList scores)

The main method should be very short. It should just declare and initialize the two array lists and then invoke these three methods.

.......As of now I have only created two arraylists and can store the names and scores. I am not certain on how I can sort and display them correctly. I've noticed people have created comparators for similar situations, but we haven't covered that yet in the class.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm trying to expand on the program right now. There's a way to input data, but I haven't figured out how to sort or display anything correctly.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: Currently the textbook doesn't offer very much in terms of finding out how to sort data in arrays. There are clues about compareTo and summing arrays, however, I am not clear on what is a good choice. I have thought about trying a 2D array but that also seems difficult to sort.

Comment: I'm going to try one last time. This is a Q&A website (read the Help Center). You've dumped your requirements, but you haven't asked a question. Is your question: "How do I sort data?"? You'll have to be much more specific.

Comment: _You'll have to be much more specific._

Comment: Do you know a way to sort the array with names and the array with scores so that it will be displayed from highest to lowest? The stuff I'm coming across through Google seem advanced and I'm not too familiar with what is being written.

Comment: You are using an ArrayList of Integer and an array list of users ,how do you guarantee the That the first Item (Player 1) is the First Player score as in the first item in the Scores list.

Comment: That's where I was thinking about a 2D array, that way I can reference [0][0] with [0][1] and possibly start from there. Using Rows and Columns may be a way but I haven't thought it through yet.

Comment: A `Map` or Player object would be better, as you are a beginner use a `HashMap<String,Integer>` player name , score. Later on progress to a Player object

Comment: I'm not familiar with that part of Java, can you explain it?

Comment: @Jared, what you are asking for is too big or off topic for this type of forum, but here is a tutorial on HashMap http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm

Comment: @Jared Could you list the parts of Java that you are familiar with?

Comment: @Evan we've worked on Arrays, methods, loops, but not many complicated problems. Most assignments so far in the course have felt kind of random and distant from the material in the textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Map i think u can achieve your target easily as below

`Map<String,Integer>` store name in string and score in integer and sort them using comparator

```
Set<Entry<String,Integer>> s=yourMap.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String,Integer>> l=new ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>>(s);
    Collections.sort(l,new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> arg0,
                Entry<String, Integer> arg1) {

            return (arg0.getValue().compareTo(arg1.getValue()));
        }

    });
```

The below code will completely satisfies your requirement just copy and run it in your eclipse

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sample
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String,Integer> dataMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
         Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner (System.in);
         Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner (System.in);

         // Ask the user for the names and scores for 5 people.

         for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
         {
         System.out.println(i+". Enter the name ");
         String name= keyboard1.next();
         System.out.println(i+". Enter the score");         
         int score=keyboard2.nextInt();
         dataMap.put(name, score);
         }


         Set<Entry<String,Integer>> s=dataMap.entrySet();
            List<Entry<String,Integer>> l=new ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>>(s);
            Collections.sort(l,new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> arg0,
                        Entry<String, Integer> arg1) {

                    return (arg1.getValue().compareTo(arg0.getValue()));
                }

            });

            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:l){
                System.out.println("Name of Student== "+entry.getKey()+"  and his Score=="+entry.getValue());
            }
    }

    }
```

**Note:if you are Once satisfied by answer please do up-vote and accept the answer**

Comment: I don't understand this, can you explain?

Comment: You are taking inputs as a name and his score one by one randomly, once done with it your target is to display in descending order as of having scores.my above code is when ever you take inputs take a map and save name as key and score as value and later to that map apply comparator as it is above and iterate that list so, that you will get the output as your target... i think this explanation more enough to understand

Comment: I'm not familiar with implementing this into the actual program. Can you explain where this should be placed?